# Intellij IDEA not detecing rsync in the SSH run target

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to setup a SSH run target in Intellij IDEA. The remote machine is an Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2.

IDEA fails to detect rsync in the remote machine, and gives following output.

[image]

But, rsync is available in the machine.

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ which rsync
/usr/local/bin/rsync
```

What could be the reason for this? Any way to troubleshoot what is the PATH which IDEA detects?

Comment: Normally, this means that `rsync` can't be found on your local machine. Are you sure it is installed on your computer?